# Combining to eliminate [pro] & [tools]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-removal-request

I've been going through and editing the improperly entered tags [pro](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro) and [tools](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) and changing them to either [pro-tools](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-tools), or [pro-tools-10](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-tools-10) (or whatever version) if there's a specification of the version that the answer depends on.

There are just a dozen or so left to do when I realized that this was a thing. Sorry for jumping the gun.

Comment: No worries... good on you :)

Comment: Great initiative Steve!

Comment: As far as I can tell it's done. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Marking this one status-completed, great work Steve! BTW, for painfully obvious cleanups you can feel free to jump in, posting here just gets you some additional help getting it straightened out. If a tag change might somehow be controversial, then it's good to start here before doing anything.

Comment: what's wrong with "protools" ?

Comment: Just an attempt to be consistent and lazy @Georgi, there were more "pro-tools" tags and its variations than "protools" tags.